# Чтение и запись в Room

Tags: java, android, android-room

Решил ознакомиться с Room. Поискал в интернете уроки, понял основные принципы работы, кроме одного. А именно: как читать и записывать данные?

У меня есть экспериментальное приложение. Идея простая: пользователь вводит свой логин, имя и возраст и нажимает кнопку "Save", если ему надо сохранить информацию. Если же он её уже сохранял ранее и хочет её открыть, то он вводит свой логин и нажимает кнопку "Open", после чего поля с именем и возрастом заполняются ранее введенными данными. Единственная проблема: как это сделать?

Из главного потока сохранять или читать данные нельзя, что логично. Хотел в OnClickListener кнопки "Save" создать поток, записывающий данные в БД, а в OnClickListener кнопки "Open" создать поток, читающий данные из БД, но и так нельзя: операции чтения и записи должны происходить в одном потоке. AsyncTask c версии Android 11 - deprecated. Какие есть способы для решения задачи? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Чтение и запись не обязаны происходить в одном потоке, главное чтобы они не выполнялись на главном потоке (ui)

Comment: Гугл в своих туториалах [использует 
класс Executor](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide) для реализации асинхронной записи. При чтении используется LiveData, это асинхронная операция и дополнительно запускать ее в асинхронном потоке не требуется

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

Решений тьма, можно как написал pavloff

> Гугл в своих туториалах использует класс Executor для реализации асинхронной записи. При чтении используется LiveData, это асинхронная операция и дополнительно запускать ее в асинхронном потоке не требуется

Если используете Kotlin то корутины, для них есть прекрасное расширение
Можно rx-java так же использовать для асинхроного чтение] и записи
Ну и на худой конец, если вы пока не освоили ни одного из инструментов, для асинхронной работы, но потрогать room очень хочется то проверку на главный поток можно отключить - добавить в билдер

```
    var db = Room.databaseBuilder(
        applicationContext,
        AppDb::class.java, "database")
        .allowMainThreadQueries() //отключает проверку
        .build()
```

После этого можете записывать и читать на любом потоке. Но лучше так не делайте и разберитесь с асинхронной работой

Comment: Про allowMainThreadQueries() я знал, но в том то и дело, что хотелось сделать правильно. Проблему уже решил благодаря ссылке от pavlofff.